# Estimating integrated-out variables

Tags: estimation, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

##### An illustration

David Blei in his [lecture notes](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Eblei/fogm/2015F/notes/mixtures-and-gibbs.pdf) considers a collapsed Gibbs sampler for a Gaussian mixture model. In this case $B = (\mu_1, \dotsc, \mu_K)$ is a latent vector of means and $A = (Z_1, \dotsc, Z_P)$ is the vector of latent indicators, assigning the $p$th point to cluster $Z_P\in \{1, \dotsc, K\}$.

Collapsing $B$ can result in faster convergence on $A$, so that many samples can be drawn. However, once the chain has converged, no information is known about $B$.

I imagine that in this case one could try to estimate $B$ by taking the MAP estimates for each $Z_P$ (that is, do the hard assignment of points into clusters) and calculate empirical mean within each cluster.

This approach however ignores:

- the uncertainty on $B$ even when all the assignments in $A$ were exact and
- the uncertainty in $A$.

Is there a more principled way of estimating the means in this case, together with some measure of uncertainty?

##### The general question

Let's now formalize the problem.
Consider a model with two latent variables $A$ and $B$, and an observed data variable $X$.
For this model we assume that:

1. Sampling from $P(A, B\mid X)$ is *hard* (e.g., sampling from $P(B\mid A,\, X)$ could be *hard*).
2. Sampling from $P(A\mid B,\, X)$ is *easy*.
3. Sampling from $P(A\mid X)$ is *easy*.

Hence:

- Metropolis–Hastings to sample directly from $P(A, B\mid X)$ will not really work.
- A Gibbs sampler to alternate between $P(B\mid A,\, X)$ and $P(A\mid B,\, X)$ will not work either.
- It is easy to collect a lot of samples $a_1, \dotsc, a_N$ from the collapsed $P(A\mid X)$ and the chain quickly converges.

The question:

> How can samples $a_1, \dotsc, a_N$ be used to estimate $B$?